# Optimize nested loop ("for") in python for n valuen

Tags: python

I need to identify all the points in a ratio of 5 km checking all the posible ubications. The thing is that i have a lot of posibles points (2,000) and what i did was a loop check every point whit the other, i mean 2,000X2,000 times.

I wanna know if there is a process to optimize this code because it takes a lot of time runing.

thanks for your help.

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy import distance
from geopy import Point

df_geoloc_eess= pd.read_excel("eess_zonacentro.xlsx")

dist_km=[]
ar_eess_cand=[]
ar_eess_comp=[]
ar_lats_cand=[]
ar_lons_cand=[]
ar_lats_comp=[]
ar_lons_comp=[]

distancia=[]
for i in range(len(df_geoloc_eess.index)):

    lats_cand=df_geoloc_eess['latitud'][i]
    lons_cand=df_geoloc_eess['longitud'][i]
    eess_cand=df_geoloc_eess["num_pemex"][i]

    for j in range(len(df_geoloc_eess.index)):

        lats_comp=df_geoloc_eess['latitud'][j]
        lons_comp=df_geoloc_eess['longitud'][j]
        eess_comp=df_geoloc_eess["num_pemex"][j]

        point_cand=Point(lats_cand,lons_cand)
        point_comp=Point(lats_comp,lons_cand)

        dist_km=distance.distance(point_cand,point_comp).km

        if dist_km<5:

            distancia.append(dist_km)

            ar_eess_cand.append(eess_cand)
            ar_lats_cand.append(lats_cand)
            ar_lons_cand.append(lons_cand)

            ar_eess_comp.append(eess_comp)
            ar_lats_comp.append(lats_comp)
            ar_lons_comp.append(lons_comp)

            dta={'candidata':ar_eess_cand,'competencias':ar_eess_comp,'latitud':ar_lats_comp,'longitud':ar_lons_comp,'distancia':distancia}
            matiz_dist=pd.DataFrame(dta)
```

Comment: What are those braces encapsulating your entire code doing in your Python code?

Comment: Also, what library is this? `geopandas`?

Comment: Fundamentally, you need a different algorithm. It sounds like you might be able tot take advantage of a space-partitioning data-structure, e.g. a kd-tree, to make your queries perform better than a brute-force polynomial-time solution.

Comment: You should really try to explain your problem, give the context and introduce the library/tools you are using.

Comment: sorry all, i new in this, ingore the braces i thought it was necesary to include my code. I used this library 1)import pandas as pd,
2)from geopy import distance,
3)from geopy import Point,